# Bin pandas dataframe by integer values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to bin the data by values of a single column. E.G. 0-1, 1-2, etc, starting at 0 and ending at 1, with intervals of 0.1, taking the mean of each column within each bin.

I'm attempting to accomplish this using the .groupby functionality of pandas. See my code below:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 my_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100),
                   "b": np.random.random(100),
                   "id": np.arange(100)})


 bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 0.1)
 groups = my_df.groupby(np.digitize(my_df.a, bins))

 binned_data = groups.mean()

 print binned_data
```

The print line then gives a single row with index "1", even though the data of column "a" should have a range of values for the bins specified.

I think its a problem with the creation of "bins" but I can't work out what.

I want 10 rows binned from 0 to 1 in 0.1 intervals. How can I accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Comment: _the last argument_, `bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)` not `0.1`.

Comment: Ah, a schoolboy misunderstanding on my part. Many thanks.